# SQL Oracle simple question about assigning varables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a question about the basics of Oracle SQL.

I want to write a function in which selectem takes a value from a very simple table, and have it as a variable.

Then check its value.

```
CREATE TABLE validationPartyMgm 
(
    id INT,    
    EvnetType VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO validationPartyMgm (id, EvnetType) 
VALUES (1, 'IndividualCreatenotification');

INSERT INTO validationPartyMgm (id, EvnetType) 
VALUES (2, 'IndividualUpdateNotification');

INSERT INTO validationPartyMgm (id, EvnetType) 
VALUES (3, 'IndividualDeleteNotification');
/

SELECT EVNETTYPE FROM validationPartyMgm 
WHERE EVNETTYPE = 'IndividualCreatenotification' ;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_valid_eventType (evnetTypeValidation IN VARCHAR2 )RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
CURSOR val IS 
SELECT EVNETTYPE FROM validationPartyMgm 
WHERE EVNETTYPE = evnetTypeValidation ;
test EVNETTYPE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN val;
FETCH val INTO test;
close val;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(test.EvnetType);
if (test.EvnetType = 'INDIVIDUALCREATENOTIFICATION')
then
return 'ok';
else return '1';
end if;
END is_valid_eventType ;
/

SELECT is_valid_eventType ('INDIVIDUALCREATENOTIFICATION') from dual ;
/
```

Comment: What is the question?  I see code but I don't see a question that we can answer...

Comment: How can i use value from table as variable in this case variable test

Comment: For example you can change declaration `test EVNETTYPE%ROWTYPE;` to `test val%ROWTYPE;`. Then your function compiles.

Comment: You are fetching the result into test:  "FETCH val INTO test;"  Please clarily your question - is there an errors?Also indent your code

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand what you're asking.  My guess is that your code is getting a compilation error that you're not showing.  My guess is that compilation error relates to the fact that you've declared `test` as a `%rowtype` variable for a table with two columns but your query is selecting only one column.  My guess is that you want to declare `test` as a scalar and do a `select into` to populate it rather than using a cursor.

Comment: Ok, so I am tottaly newbie in sql . I am trying to check in last line : "SELECT is_valid_eventType ('INDIVIDUALCREATENOTIFICATION') from dual ; " String exist . So i wrote a function. But I HAVE NO IDEA how can i get value from table inside my function  SELECT EVNETTYPE FROM validationPartyMgm 
WHERE EVNETTYPE = evnetTypeValidation ; and use it

Comment: this code as you show it does not even compile.  Please post a [mcve].  thanks

Comment: Ok so How can I assign result from select to variable and use it ? I just want to assign value from select statement to a variable

Comment: SQL is a query language (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE etc). PL/SQL is a programming language. I think you are talking about PL/SQL, not SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance like here:

```
create or replace function is_valid_eventtype (evnettypevalidation in varchar2)
    return varchar2 is 
    v_test validationpartymgm.evnettype%type;
begin
    begin 
        select evnettype into v_test 
            from validationpartymgm  
            where evnettype = evnetTypeValidation;
    exception 
        when no_data_found then
            return 'error: no such event type';
        when too_many_rows then
            return 'error: many events';
    end;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_test);
    return 'ok';
end is_valid_eventType ;
```

and use it:

```
select is_valid_eventType ('IndividualCreatenotification') from dual ;  -- ok
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're asking how to write a function to validate a parameter using a table. Here's two simple ways to do that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_valid_eventType (evnetTypeValidation IN VARCHAR2 )
RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS
BEGIN
    -- implicit cursor loop
    for r in (SELECT EVNETTYPE FROM validationPartyMgm 
        WHERE EVNETTYPE = evnetTypeValidation)
    loop
        return 'ok';
    end loop;
    return 'not valid';

END is_valid_eventType ;
/
```

This one uses an **implicit cursor loop**, and exits the first time it finds a matching row in the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_valid_eventType (evnetTypeValidation IN VARCHAR2 )
RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS
    v_valid validationPartyMgm.EVNETTYPE%TYPE;
BEGIN
    -- use SELECT INTO - will raise NO_DATA_FOUND if 
    SELECT EVNETTYPE 
        INTO v_valid
        FROM validationPartyMgm 
        WHERE EVNETTYPE = evnetTypeValidation;
    return 'ok';
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN -- parameter was not found in the table
        return 'not valid';
END is_valid_eventType ;
/
```

This one uses `SELECT INTO`, which you need exception handlers for.

Also note that your example code should not return 'ok', since the parameter you're trying to test doesn't match any of the values in the table - it's all uppercase.

```
SELECT is_valid_eventType ('IndividualCreatenotification') from dual ;
-- return 'ok'. note case-sensitivity
SELECT is_valid_eventType ('INDIVIDUALCREATENOTIFICATION') from dual ;
-- returns 'not valid'
```

If you want your validation function to be case-insensitive, you'll want to change the queries above to `WHERE upper(EVNETTYPE) = upper(evnetTypeValidation)`, or something similar.